# Regex match account number in PDF until new line

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm working on a pdf **scraper** in C# and I got stuck on a regex problem. I want to match just the account number and my regex statement is matching both the incorrect line and the correct line. I think I have to match everything until a new line but I can't find a way to do it.

```
This is my regex: ([A-Z0-9\-]{5,30})-[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{3}

XXX-XX-914026-1558513  // I don't want to match this line

130600298-110-528   // I want to match this line
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add anchors:

```
^([A-Z0-9\-]{5,30})-[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{3}$
^                                       ^
```

Which mean start of line (`^`) and end of line (`$`).

If you don't, the match will be:

```
XXX-XX-914026-1558513
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Also, you don't have to escape the caret in the end of a character class and you can use `\d` instead of [0-9]<sup>note: this will match numbers in any charset</sup> which gives:

```
^([A-Z0-9-]{5,30})-\d{1,10}-\d{3}$
```